# How often does Google refresh its cached websites?

Tags: caching, google-search

If you type in [cache:www.92spoons.com](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?source=hp&ei=N_L4WbqIHerSjwSs6qPwAg&q=cache%3Awww.92spoons.com&oq=cache%3Awww.92spoons.com&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1494.9764.0.9976.28.24.2.0.0.0.478.3075.5j6j2j1j2.16.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..10.6.1134.0..0j46j35i39k1j0i67k1j0i131k1j0i20i264k1j0i46k1j0i20i264i46k1j46i20i264k1.0.d9i_J3cBiDs), for example, into the Google search engine, it shows you a snapshot of the page from a time when Google snapshotted the site. I was just wondering, how often does Google refresh its cached data? It looks like, as of now, it was refreshed about 3 days ago. Also, do all sites' cached data update at the same time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is based on how often the website is changed. For example, Wikipedia may be updated several times a day, but 92spoons.com may be updated every few days. ([source](https://www.quora.com/How-long-does-it-take-for-Google-to-clear-cached-websites-and-are-cached-versions-of-temporary-pastebins-removed))

This also can be changed by popularity. You can visit [this website](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) which should allow you to refresh the cache. ([source](https://support.google.com/websearch/forum/AAAAgtjJeM4L0PG1j9yZDA/?hl=en))